# IOS CollectionView where cell is 1/3 of the container

Tags: ios

I would like to set up a 3x3 grid view in IOS.

I want the width of the cell to be 1/3 of the parent container's width, and the height of the cell to equal to the width of the cell.

Is there a way to set this up directly in an interface builder? So each grid with contain some label and buttons and they are all centered in each cell.

Currently I tried doing 3 nested layers of horizontal and vertical stackView. But it seems rather sketchy. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it with colleciton view?

Comment: "Is there a way to set this up in an interface builder" No, you'd need to give the cell size at runtime when you know the parent container's width, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well it can be done in android..

Comment: @user1017674 To make things easier for people, maybe take your effort to: 1: What you have done so far? 2: What problems you run into? 3: Do some painting in what you want to achieve and add your image to the question to make it easier to give you alternative solutions.

Comment: I actually solved the problem with 2 layers of nested stack views. First vertical stackView. and 3 horizontal stack views. That allowed me to partition the container view into a 3x3 grid. I wonder if there are easier ways with a collection view.

Comment: You could try making an equal width constraint between the two views, and setting the multiplier to 1/3.

Comment: My comment was _about_ a collection view. I thought that's what you were using (or wanted to use). As I said, you'd give the cell size at runtime. It's a one-liner; I don't see why this is an issue. Even better, you'd write your own collection view layout; that is the best way to automate the creation of a grid layout (Apple's iBooks library view is a good example).

Comment: @matt I see. I just wasn't familiar with IOS enough. I personally hate to write device size specific code in application code. Do you mind giving me some links that show me what needs to be done? I do believe using the a collection view/grid view is the more correct approach... I just don't know how..

Comment: Googling "uicollectionview grid layout" turns up a lot of promising leads!